# How to get the connection strength of Wifi access points?

Tags: android, wifi

I am building an application reading the signal strength of each available Wifi access point.

I've written code like:

```
    wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    // Get WiFi status
    WifiInfo info = wifi.getConnectionInfo();
    textStatus.append("\n\nWiFi Status: " + info.toString());

    // List available networks
    List<WifiConfiguration> configs = wifi.getConfiguredNetworks();
```

However, I have two problems:

1. In debugging, `configs` only contains one connection. However, I can see that there are several APs available in the system's wifi setting. I.e. `configs` is an incomplete list.
2. I don't know how to get the signal strength in `WifiConfiguration`.

btw, I am using HTC Hero and Android 1.5.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to the Android API documentation [WifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#getConfiguredNetworks()) does not fill the signal strength paramters. This data only represents the remembered access point settings, not the visible ones.

To get actually visible networks you must call [WifiManager.startScan()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#startScan()) to initiate WiFi radio scanning and [WifiManager.getScanResults()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#getScanResults()) after a while to get the scanning results.

Comment: How long do you exactly mean by "a while"? Isn't there any blocking call to this API method?

Comment: It's usually 2-10 seconds (but no restrictions are implied really). But keep in mind, you may miss some visible access points if you scan for too short.

Wi-Fi access points are detected by special broadcast packets (so called "beacons") which are emitted periodically. Scanning for access points actually means listening for the beacons and collecting them.
http://www.wi-fiplanet.com/tutorials/article.php/1492071

Comment: There is no synchronous function for the whole process. Though you may just call getScanResults() to get results of a previous scan performed by the system. Maybe that results are fresh enough for your purpose.
However I won't expect it to be good if you have an active WiFi connection - I think the Android system components don't run scans when a good connection is present. There is just no reason to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I am actually writing a simple app to record wifi perception around the site. So, user has a single button and as he/she presses the button wifi access point perceptions are recorded into a database. With such a mechanism, on every button press the user should stand still for a few seconds.

Comment: Calling a synchronous function isn't a good solution anyway. Android will show the ANR (Application Not Responding) warnings for your application if you block for too long in the UI thread.
Consider disabling the button during a scan process, that fits the event-based UI model better.

Comment: Great tips friend! I have set it to something in middle, something about 5 secs and looks like it is working perfectly...

Answer (score 7):

below code will help to get bar of wifi:

```
registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            int state = wifi.getWifiState();
            if(state == WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED) {
                List<ScanResult> results = wifi.getScanResults();

                for (ScanResult result : results) {
                    if(result.BSSID.equals(wifi.getConnectionInfo().getBSSID())) {
                        int level = WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(wifi.getConnectionInfo().getRssi(),
                                result.level);
                        int difference = level * 100 / result.level;
                        int signalStrangth= 0;
                        if(difference >= 100)
                            signalStrangth = 4;
                        else if(difference >= 75)
                            signalStrangth = 3;
                        else if(difference >= 50)
                            signalStrangth = 2;
                        else if(difference >= 25)
                            signalStrangth = 1;
                        tv.setText(tv.getText() + "\nDifference :" + difference + " signal state:" + signalStrangth);

                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.RSSI_CHANGED_ACTION));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
mainWifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
receiverWifi = new WifiReceiver();
    registerReceiver(receiverWifi, new IntentFilter(
            WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {

        List<ScanResult> wifiList = mainWifi.getScanResults();
        ArrayList<WifiConnectionBean> m4MessagesList = new ArrayList<WifiConnectionBean>();
        for (int i = 0; i < wifiList.size(); i++) {
            ScanResult scanResult = wifiList.get(i);
            WifiConnectionBean bean = new WifiConnectionBean();
            bean.setConnectionName(scanResult.SSID); // + "--" +
                                                        // scanResult.frequency);
            bean.setDescription(scanResult.capabilities);
            bean.setId(scanResult.SSID);
            bean.setLevel(String.valueOf(scanResult.level));
            bean.setSignalStrength(String.valueOf(scanResult.BSSID));
            m4MessagesList.add(bean);
        }
        if (m4MessagesList == null) {
            Toast.makeText(WifiIdentificationActivity.this,
                    "WifiConnection not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else {
            String message = "Scanning complete. " + m4MessagesList.size()
                    + " connections found!";
        }
        pd.dismiss();

    }
}
```

where scanResult.SSID gives the signal strength.

Comment: I don't think either BSSID or SSID gives the signal strength.
SSID returns the access point name while BSID returns the address of the access point. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html

Answer (score 1):

```
private void checkNetworkStrengh() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo Info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (Info == null || !Info.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "No connection");
        } else {
            int netType = Info.getType();
            int netSubtype = Info.getSubtype();

            if (netType == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Wifi connection");
                WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplication().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                List<ScanResult> scanResult = wifiManager.getScanResults();
                for (int i = 0; i < scanResult.size(); i++) {
                    Log.d("scanResult", "Speed of wifi"+scanResult.get(i).level);//The db level of signal 
                }


                // Need to get wifi strength
            } else if (netType == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                Log.i(TAG, "GPRS/3G connection");
                // Need to get differentiate between 3G/GPRS
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)
    MonitorActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);

    int numberOfLevels = 5;
    WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    int level = WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(wifiInfo.getRssi(), numberOfLevels);

    Log.e("level", "" + level);
    // you will get the levels. Using these levels you can calculate strenghts.
```