# How to get Wi Fi and Cell Network Signal Strength

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi, wifimanager

Can I get the current WiFi and Cell Network strength in my android application. Is there is any broadcast of function available in the API to get the current data.

Comment: Man, googling (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437694/how-to-get-the-connection-strength-of-wifi-access-points and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967136/how-to-get-cell-service-signal-strength-in-android) is so hard...

Answer (score 3):

For cell info you need this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/package-summary.html I suppose. 
And http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html for wifi