# Get signal strength of wifi connection from Android drivers in terminal

Tags: android, linux, wifi, adb

I am able to get RSSI for the current wifi network with the following command, but I need a command with faster response, this one is too slow:

```
dumpsys wifi | grep ", RSSI"
```

Is there a better way to get the signal strength from the android linux terminal?

I've also tried WifiInfo.getRssi() in java and it has about a 2 second delay between samples.  I need about 200ms.

Comment: did you see this answer?http://stackoverflow.com/a/4173396/2101822

Comment: please take a look at the comments they said it usualy takes 2-10 secs

Comment: That is referring to how long it takes before you get data after starting a scan, not how often you can sample the rss on the network you are connected to.

Answer (score 0):

Use the command below to change the rssi update interval to 200 ms. You may need root privilege.

```
adb shell cmd wifi set-poll-rssi-interval-msecs 200
```

> I've also tried WifiInfo.getRssi() in java and it has about a 2 second delay between samples.

Yes, the default update interval is 3000 ms.

---

You can find the implementation in  `frameworks/opt/net/wifi/service/java/com/android/server/wifi/ClientModeImpl.java`. In short, it updates the wifi state by wificond process, which communicates with the Wi-Fi driver over standard nl80211 commands. The update time interval is the private field `mPollRssiIntervalMsecs`. The class exposes this field by `cmd` command (see the `WifiShellCommand` class).