# Wifi Signal Strength Level On android phone with linux and python

Tags: android, python, linux, shell

How can I get Wifi Signal Strength Level On android phone with linux? My Android phone is plug in via usb to linux. I use adb module to communicate with my phone "adb shell". I access in android shell and I search the file or the directory in the android phone shell with the Wifi Signal Strength Level. I would like use a linux command from python via popen module.

Comment: The output from `adb shell "dumpsys | grep RSSI:"` might be challenging to parse from a python subprocess.  Your line of least resistance is to snarf and modify some of the code from the question I linked to and install that on your phone. Then call that from `subprocess.call()`

Comment: Thanks it's clear for me.

Answer (score 2):

Android will give you the WiFi signal strength as an [RSSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Received_signal_strength_indication) value. This will be a number between -100 and 0 dBm, where 0 is the strongest and -100 is the weakest signal.

A quick and easy method to find the RSSI via adb shell is to use [dumpsys](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/dumpsys.html)

For example:
`adb shell "dumpsys | grep RSSI:"`

There are some related questions [getting-wifi-signal-strength-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932724/getting-wifi-signal-strength-in-android?rq=1) and  [how-to-get-the-connection-strength-of-wifi-access-points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437694/how-to-get-the-connection-strength-of-wifi-access-points/4173396) that are worth reading if you would like to write a more directed tool for the job.

[WifiManager.startScan()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#startScan()) and
[WifiManager.getScanResults()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#getScanResults()) are the api calls you would use for that.

Comment: I have an other question. I would like to find the Wifi Signal Strength Level in percent. Because with adb shell "dumpsys | grep RSSI:" command I have just the signal strength in dbm.

Comment: @search-solution What steps have to taken to solve this problem yourself?